# Ruby Selenium - How to check if text is present only once

Tags: ruby, testing, selenium

I am working on a application that reports status updates on certain services. I am using **Ruby Selenium** for testing the application.

For the same purpose I wana test some updates that are just plain text - these updates should appear exactly once in the page. **Thus, how can I test if a web page has some text only once ?**

I am looking for something like

**assertTextPresentOnlyOnce ??**

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking something like this..:

```
!20.times { break if (selenium.is_visible(driver.find_element(:id, 'loginid')) 
rescue false ); sleep 1}
        .
        .
[rest of the code you want to execute]
        .
        .
```

This will cover you and for page time-out as well if the element you want is not present yet. As soon as selenium finds the element you want the loop will break and the code below will be executed.